# Facebook iOS SDK: can't show a "direct message" dialog on iPad (works on an iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

I'm using the iOS Facebook SDK version 3.19 (the latest, at the time of writing). I'd like to use their "Direct message" dialog. I call the method:

`[FBDialogs canPresentMessageDialog]`

and after getting a `YES`:

`[FBDialogs  presentMessageDialogWithLink:name:caption:description:picture:clientState:handler:]`

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBDialogs/)

The flow works correctly on an iPhone with iOS7/8 (dialog shown, message sent).

On an iPad (iOS7/8), the first method (`canPresentMessageDialog`) consistently returns `NO`. Even if I ignore it and call `presentMessageDialogWithLink:name:...` either way, it has no effect. I have tested that on both iOS 7 and 8. Facebook and Messenger apps are installed and up to date.

I couldn't find any information about whether or not the Direct Message dialog is supported on iPad. In fact, their overview of iOS SDK dialogs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls) does not mention the Direct Message dialog at all.

Am I missing something obvious? Or the Direct Message dialog is just not supported on an iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There is an official statement from Facebook for that issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/389140797915569/?comment_id=763954750352881)

> "We currently don't support the message dialog on the iPad"

Answer (score 3):

There's no official documentation of this, but I can confirm that canPresentMessageDialog always returns NO from the iPad while it works fine on the iPhone.